# Reloading/refreshing Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to reload or refresh a Kendo Grid using Javascript?

It is often required to reload or refresh a grid after sometime or after a user action.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

You can use

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read(); <!--  first reload data source -->

$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh(); <!--  refresh current UI -->
```

Comment: @zespri `read` will request the server and reload **only** reload datasource. There will be no changes in the UI. `refresh` will re-render items in grid from the current datasource. That's why both are required.

Comment: I don't think you need the refresh in the latest version of Kendo. As it seems to work fine without it

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. For instance removing an item with a custom command as opposed to the default "Destroy" command from within a nested detail view, requires manually refreshing.

Comment: Yeah! This work also with TreeList: $('#Gantt').data('kendoTreeList').dataSource.read();
$('#Gantt').data('kendoTreeList').refresh();

Comment: Developers explicitly say not to call refresh after read: http://www.telerik.com/forums/show-progress-spinner-during-load-refresh because it may prevent progress indicator from appearing.

Comment: Doesn't need .refresh(); as it will prevent the loading spinner to work properly.

Comment: Actually if you are on page different than 1 (> 1), you need to call `).dataSource.page(1);`. But be careful if serverPaging is true, it fires another request. To fire only one request call `dataSource.query({page: 1, pageSize: x})`.

Comment: I'm using a newer version and I only have to call .read. Calling .refresh after read causes two trips to the server for data.

Comment: In Angular just  `dataSource.data([..your new data ])` works .

Comment: "Maximum call stack size exceeded".... this happens when i call above mentioned methods

Comment: some one please show how to do it in angular 8

Answer (score 64):

I never do refresh.

```js
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
```

alone works for me all the time.

Answer (score 33):

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives "TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined" error. I also looked on many pages and tried different variations of this solution but still get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: If data('kendoGrid') returns null then most likely either the id is wrong or you haven't created the grid yet. NB you make the grid with $(..).kendoGrid() and access it later with $().data('kendoGrid')

Answer (score 32):

In a recent project, I had to update the Kendo UI Grid based on some calls, that were happening on some dropdown selects. Here is what I ended up using:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/api/....',
        data: { myIDSArray: javascriptArrayOfIDs },
        traditional: true,
        success: function(result) {
            searchResults = result;
        }
    }).done(function() {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: searchResults });
        var grid = $('#myKendoGrid').data("kendoGrid");
        dataSource.read();
        grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    });
```

Hopefully this will save you some time.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for grid.setDataSource(dataSource); for non-remote calls it's what you have to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Not a single one of these answers gets the fact that `read` returns a promise, which means you can wait for the data to load before calling refresh.

```
$('#GridId').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read().then(function() {
    $('#GridId').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
});
```

This is unnecessary if your data grab is instant/synchronous, but more than likely it's coming from an endpoint that won't return immediately.

Comment: Leveraging the built-in promise support is really convenient and removed a few lines of code too.  I would wager that this should be the true answer.

Comment: Thank you Zachary! I have spent a couple of hours on this problem - your solution is the only one that worked for me. I am inserting rows to my grid database source via ajax, looped (one row at a time). After the loop finishes dataSource.read()  worked only sometimes. "then" is what I needed. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

If you do not want to have a reference to the grid in the handler, you can use this code:

```
 $(".k-pager-refresh").trigger('click');
```

This will refresh the grid, if there is a refresh button.
The button can be enabled like so:

```
[MVC GRID DECLARATION].Pageable(p=> p.Refresh(true))
```

Answer (score 10):

Actually, they are different:

- `$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read()` refreshes the `uid` attributes of the table row
- `$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh()` leaves the same uid

Answer (score 8):

What you have to do is just add an event 
**.Events(events => events.Sync("KendoGridRefresh"))**
in your kendoGrid binding code.No need to write the refresh code in ajax result.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.DocumentDetail>().Name("document")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Id))        
    .Events(events => events.Sync("KendoGridRefresh"))    
    )
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden();              
          columns.Bound(c => c.UserName).Title(@Resources.Resource.lblAddedBy);                           
      }).Events(e => e.DataBound("onRowBound"))
          .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text(@Resources.Resource.lblNewDocument))
          .Sortable()          
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:260px" })          
  )
```

And you can add the following Global function in any of your .js file. so, you can call it for all the kendo grids in your project to refresh the kendoGrid.

```
function KendoGridRefresh() {
    var grid = $('#document').data('kendoGrid');
    grid.dataSource.read();
}
```

Comment: Refresh kendoGrid by just adding Event.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had a custom url to go to each time; though the schema of the result would remain the same.
I used the following:

```
var searchResults = null;
$.ajax({
        url: http://myhost/context/resource,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //massage results and store in searchResults
            searchResults = massageData(result);
        }
    }).done(function() {
        //Kendo grid stuff
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: searchResults });
        var grid = $('#doc-list-grid').data('kendoGrid');
        dataSource.read();
        grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

I want to go back to page 1 when I refresh the grid.  Just calling the read() function will keep you on the current page, even if the new results don't have that many pages.  Calling .page(1) on the datasource will refresh the datasource AND return to page 1 but fails on grids that aren't pageable.  This function handles both:

```
function refreshGrid(selector) {
     var grid = $(selector);
     if (grid.length === 0)
         return;

     grid = grid.data('kendoGrid');
     if (grid.getOptions().pageable) {
         grid.dataSource.page(1);
     }
     else {
         grid.dataSource.read();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I used Jquery .ajax to get data. In order to reload the data into current grid, I need to do the following:

```
.success (function (result){
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(result.data);
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below lines

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

For a auto refresh feature have a look [here](https://nitinasp.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/auto-refresh-of-kendo-grid/)

Answer (score 5):

By using following code it automatically called grid's read method and again fill grid

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way to reload the grid is

```
$("#GridName").getKendoGrid().dataSource.read();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();`. You don't really need to `.refresh();` after that, `.dataSource.read();` will do the trick.

Now if you want to refresh your grid in a more angular way, you can do:

```
<div kendo-grid="vm.grid" id="grid" options="vm.gridOptions"></div>

vm.grid.dataSource.read();`
```

**OR**

```
vm.gridOptions.dataSource.read();
```

And don't forget to declare your datasource as `kendo.data.DataSource` type

Answer (score 4):

In order to do a complete refresh, where the grid will be re-rendered alongwith new read request, you can do the following:

```
 Grid.setOptions({
      property: true/false
    });
```

Where property can be any property e.g. sortable

Answer (score 4):

You may try:

```
    $('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also refresh your grid with sending new parameters to Read action and setting pages to what you like :

```
var ds = $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
ds.options.page = 1;
var parameters = {
    id: 1
    name: 'test'
}
ds.read(parameters);
```

In this example read action of the grid is being called by 2 parameters value and after getting result the paging of the grid is in page 1.

Answer (score 3):

Just write below code

```
$('.k-i-refresh').click();
```

Comment: This would be true only if you have initialized the grid with a pageable.refresh = true... which isn't by default.  Anyway, you should not use a UI workaround when you are able to do it using an API function (see accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#theidofthegrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data([ ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are desiring the grid to be automatically refreshed on a timed basis, you can use the following example which has the interval set at 30 seconds:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
         setInterval(function () {
            var grid = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.read();
         }, 30000);
      });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default/updated configuration/data of the widgets is set to automatically bind to an associated DataSource.

```
$('#GridId').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
$('#GridId').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

Comment: Was there something wrong with the accepted answer (from 2013), since your answer looks so similar. You should at least comment that some way -- and the comments in that answer even say that you should not call `refresh`

Answer (score 2):

I see that a lot of answers here suggest calling both `dataSource.read` and `grid.refresh`, however, internally the grid listens for dataSource changes and upon a change it will refresh itself. In other words executing both `dataSource.read` and `grid.refresh` will result in refreshing the grid twice, which is unnecessary. Calling just `dataSource.read` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way out to refresh is using the refresh() function. 
Which goes like:

```
$('#gridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

while you can also refresh the data source using this command:

```
$('#gridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
```

The latter actually reloads the data source of the grid. The use of both can be done according to your need and requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**common js function for refresh kendo grid**

```
function refreshKendoGrid(id) {
var grid = $("#" + id).data("kendoGrid");
if (grid) {
    grid.dataSource.read();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Piling on with an observation. Zachary Dow gave me some interesting to work with. I took at face value the common suggestion of:

```
var grid = $("#grid");
grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.refresh();
```

My experience (YMMV) was that the refresh took place, but the spinner didn't work. Data just refreshed after a 2-second visual desert of nothing. I then tried this:

```
var grid = $("#grid");
kendo.ui.progress(grid, false);
grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.refresh();
kendo.ui.progress(grid, true);
```

That accomplished nothing.

Then, thanks to Zachary's observation, I tried something like this.

```
var grid = $("#grid");
kendo.ui.progress(grid, true);
grid
  .data("kendoGrid")
  .dataSource
  .read()
  .then(function() {
    kendo.ui.progress(grid, false);
  });
grid.data("kendoGrid").refresh();
}
```

(I'm going by memory here, so a step in this progress might be off.)

That had the interesting effect of producing *two* spinners.

At this point I tried another person's answer from this post, and removed all the bling. (And I'll get to my point.)

```
var grid = $("#grid");
grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

That did the trick. So this is a long story with the same punchline. My *problem* turned out to be the refresh() call. Remove it, and I got a refresh with a function spinner.

Answer (score -2):

My solution is:

```
var gridObj = $('#GridName').data('kendoGrid');
gridObj.dataSource.read();
gridObj.refresh();
```

Works also for other object functions

Answer (score -3):

```
$("#grd").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

Comment: While this is at least no 1to1 copy paste, it provides no additional information. Almost every answer in this post with more than one upvote recommended using `dataSource.read()`

Answer (score -3):

$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read(); //first you have to read the datasource data
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh(); // after that you can refresh

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Isn't it the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18399994/2227743)?