# How to refresh the KendoUi grid after a ajax post callback

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to refresh the kendo ui grid after a ajax post is successful?
Here is my grid ajax post:

```
 var newUser = {
                    UserId: 0,
                    UserLoginName: currentRecord.UserLoginName,
                    UserDisplayName: currentRecord.UserDisplayName
                };
                //insert selected rows using DataSource insert method
                destinationGrid.dataSource.insert(newRecord);
                //ajax post to server
                var url = '@Url.Action("CreateUser", "ManageUsers")';
                $.post(url, { loginid: currentRecord.UserLoginName, name: currentRecord.UserDisplayName, role: roleSelected }, function (result) {
                    if (result.Success) {
        **////grid is not refreshing as I want to refersh the grid again from database**
                        destinationGrid.dataSource.read();
                    }

                });
            }
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399805/reloading-refreshing-kendo-grid/18399994#18399994

Comment: if you see above in my grid I am already using it and I have tried both the options below.

Comment: the below option works every where and in every event , as I have used it many times, but in the $(post(url) call back I need to refersh the grid as soon as I completes my controller action. How do I do that?

Comment: i just post code. i hope it may help you.

Comment: You should use the transport configuration for this, have a create url. After you insert a new item in the datasource, just call sync() and let the magic happen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is just example

```
 $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("NewGridView", "Test")',
          type: "Post",
          data: { sampleItem: sampleItem, sampleCode: sampleCode, sampledescription: sampledescription },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (result) {

     $('#gridName').data("kendoGrid").dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: result });
     $('#gridName').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
     $('#gridName').data("kendoGrid").refresh();
}
});
```

**Controller**

```
 public JsonResult NewGridView(string sampleItem, string sampleCode, string sampledescription)
        {

        List<SampleModel> sampleAddList = new List<SampleModel>();
        SampleModel sampleAdd = new SampleModel();
        sampleAdd.SampleCode = sampleCode;
        sampleAdd.SampleDescription = sampledescription;
        sampleAdd.SampleItems = sampleItem;

        sampleAddList.Add(sampleAdd);
        var result = sampleAddList;
       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

if you need to refresh your grid as soon as complate controller action do this,

`$('#gridName').data("kendoGrid").dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: result });` in your `post success`

Comment: Thanks It worked, but newly added rows are going to the bottom of table, how Can i make it at the first row?

Comment: @Deepali i thing you have to do order by created date desc in your controller.

Comment: .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Top))   will make sure the new line is inserted at the top

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand you need refresh your kendo grid after a successful update (equivalent to $.ajax `success:` callback) right?

In that case kendo grid doesn't have any success callback, instead they use a `complete` callback. Try the following in the transport;

```
dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/YourController/LoadYourGridData",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "/YourController/UpdateYourGridData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                complete: function (data) {

                    $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$("#gridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

OR

```
$("#gridName").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```