# How to refresh kendo grid?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have data in kendo grid so on below api call i am deleting row record that is working at backend side but its not refreshing grid on client side. How can i refresh grid ?

So far tried code
main.js

```
$scope.excludeAssess = function(key){ RcsaFactory.assessmentDetails(key.riskAssessmentKey,'RS_DELETED').then(function(){
                $scope.includeAssOptions.dataSource.read();
              });
            };
    $scope.includeAssOptions = RcsaAssessConfig.includeAssessmentGrid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You already **read the dataSource** but then you missed the second step which is **refreshing the kendo grid**, there is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399805/reloading-refreshing-kendo-grid). Assuming `$scope.includeAssOptions` is your grid then you could simply `$scope.includeAssOptions.refresh();`  to refresh your grid