# Edit master column Title in kendo grid on clicking column headers in detailInit

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

Following is a kendo grid sample with detailInit:

[image]

My requirement is that on sorting a column in a particular sub-grid(detailInit), its header i.e. FirstName field should be changed like shown below:

[image]

Just that particular sub-grid's header should be changed. I have tried by registering onclick event in databound function of detailInit but unable to find the column header and change it :

```
$("th[role='columnheader']").on("click", function (ev) {

// access clicked column in sub- grid
// change master row's title
    };
```

Please someone suggest me a solution as I am new to kendo grid, js, HTML, so not aware of many functions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Please find my code below :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>

        var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                },
                pageSize: 6,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true
            },
            height: 450,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            detailInit: detailInit,
            dataBound: function () {
                this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
            },
            columns: [
              {
                  field: "FirstName",
                  title: " "
              }
            ]
        }).on("click", ".btn-refresh", function (e) {
            debugger;
            var childGrid = $(e.target).closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
            childGrid.dataSource.read();
        });

        function detailInit(e) {
            $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                    },
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    pageSize: 6,
                    filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.EmployeeID }
                },
                scrollable: false,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                toolbar: [{ text: "Refresh", className: "btn-refresh" }],
                columns: [
                  { field: "OrderID", width: 70 },
                  { field: "ShipCountry", title: "Ship Country", width: 100 },
                  { field: "ShipAddress", title: "Ship Address" },
                  {
                      field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: 200
                  }
                ]
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, at least, two main ways to do this. However, I didn't understand if you want to:

**a)** Clear all the "updated" texts, letting only the last clicked with it

**b)** Keep all them tracked, putting the text as the user sorts the grids

Anyway, let's see both strategies.

### Using jQuery only

**a)**

```
element.on('click', "th[role='columnheader']", function(e) {
    // always remove all, to put again in the right place
    $("strong[attr-id=updated]").remove(); 

    var firstNameCell = $(this)
        .closest("tr.k-detail-row") // Finds the closest detail row ...
        .prev("tr.k-master-row") // ... in order to get the first previous row of class "k-master-row" (which stores the FirstName)
        .find("td[role='gridcell']"); // and, then, get the td gridcell

    firstNameCell.append("<strong attr-id='updated'> - Address updated</strong>");
});
```

**b)**

```
element.on('click', "th[role='columnheader']", function(e) {
    var firstNameCell = $(this)
        .closest("tr.k-detail-row")
        .prev("tr.k-master-row")
        .find("td[role='gridcell']");

    // Check if the msg already exits, to not duplicate it
    if (!(firstNameCell).find('strong[attr-id=updated]').length) {
        firstNameCell.append("<strong attr-id='updated'> - Address updated</strong>");
    }
});
```

The `attr-id` helps to identify the text element along the page, once it's not a good practice using `id` (only once per page).

### Using KendoUI JavaScript objects

That's not the best way, since you cannot `append` HTML like we did with jQuery approach. Also, you'll have to refresh the whole table every time a sort is made.

That's why I'll show only case **b)**

```
element.on('click', "th[role='columnheader']", function(e) {
    var masterRow = $(this)
        .closest("tr.k-detail-row")
        .prev("tr.k-master-row"); // Finds the closest master row ...

    var rowIndex = $("tr.k-master-row").index(masterRow); // ... gets the index of it among all the others
    kendoGrid = element.data('kendoGrid');
    var firstName = kendoGrid.dataSource._data[rowIndex].FirstName; // gets current name based on the index

    if (!firstName.includes('Address updated')) {
        selectedCell = rowIndex; // sets the index to be used when grid refreshes
        kendoGrid.dataSource._data[rowIndex].FirstName = firstName + " - Address updated";
        kendoGrid.refresh(); // refreshed the whole grid
    }
});
```

Still, in order to make KendoUI to expand the right row every time its grids are refreshed, you have to create the global variable `selectedCell` and check at `dataBound` function whether it has a value or not:

```
dataBound: function () {
    if (selectedCell) {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row:eq(" + selectedCell + ")"));
    } else {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
},
```

Here, you can see more about Kendo Grid refreshing: [Reloading/refreshing Kendo Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399805/reloading-refreshing-kendo-grid)

Hope it helps! :)