# Close Client template from inside window

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kendo grid with detail template and inside the detail template is a button which opens a client template window which loads editable data and has button inside this window called "Update Data in SQL" which when clicked accesses a controller which updates the database which all works fine.

I need help adding code inside the controller to close the client template and refresh the grid after the database has updated.

Any information would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The detail templates will be closed automatically once the parent grid gets refreshed. Reload and refresh are explained over there: [Reloading/refreshing Kendo Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399805/reloading-refreshing-kendo-grid)