# How to refresh kendo grid periodically with javascript setinterval method

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid and i want to refresh the grid in every 5 minutes with alert that the grid will be refreshed.I tried below code but the popup is coming multiple time.

```
function showGrid()
{
----
----
refreshQueue();
}
refreshQueue()
{
 window.setInterval(function () {

        alert("Your session has expired, and grid will be refreshed with the latest data.");
        $("#queueList").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();       
    }, 600000); 
}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: How often do you call `showGrid()`? You have to set the interval only once or clear it before you set it again, see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: the grid is loaded by selecting a dropdown.I caled refreshqueue() method after the showgrid() method

Answer (score 1):

The implementation with setInterval is not the cleanest implementation. Please check Telerik implementation with SignalR. https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/signalr

Some documentation about SignalR https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr

Here is how to refresh the grid in @Jaimin answer
[Reloading/refreshing Kendo Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399805/reloading-refreshing-kendo-grid)

**Your implementation would be:**

```
setInterval(function () {
    alert("Your session has expired, and grid will be refreshed with the latest data.");
    $("#queueList").data('kendoGrid').refresh();
}, 300000);
```